# TableDirections example produces an error message

Tags: bugs, output-formatting

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.3**

---

Can anyone replicate this?  In *Mathematica* 10.2 on Win 64:

```
TableForm[{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}, TableDirections -> Row]
```

I get the following error message:

> "The specified setting for the option `GridBoxOptions`, `RowAlignments`
>   cannot be used."

Comment: I also get this in version 10.1 on Windows - the error message pops up a separate window

Comment: Works on v9. Added the "bugs" tag

Comment: confirmed on 10. as a workaround `TableAlignments -> Center` makes it work.

Comment: I get the error message with v10.2 on a Mac but the displayed table is correctly aligned..

Comment: @Alan works fine for me on 10.2, 32 bit

Comment: v10.3 on Linux: I get the same error message, but the result is correct.