# Grid with recurrence relation terms

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation, grid-layouts

I want to get the recurrence relation for several values of n in a grid form. At the moment I am using

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 2] == (1 - n)/(n + 1) a[n], a[2] == a0, a[3] == 0}, a, {n, 2, 20}]
```

To get

```
{a0, 0, -(a0/3), 0, a0/5, 0, -(a0/7), 0, a0/9, 0, -(a0/11), 0, a0/13, 0, -(a0/15), 
 0, a0/17, 0, -(a0/19)}
```

But I need it with the values of $n$ in one column running from 2 to 20 with heading `n` and the above list as a second column with heading `a[n]`. I tried something funny but it failed horribly:

```
Grid[Table[{a0, 0, -(a0/3), 0, a0/5, 0, -(a0/7), 0, a0/9, 0, -(a0/11), 0,
            a0/13, 0, -(a0/15), 0, a0/17, 0, -(a0/19)},
           {i, {i, 2, 20}}
     ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you want.

```
list = RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 2] == (1 - n)/(n + 1) a[n], a[2] == a0, a[3] == 0}, 
   a, {n, 2, 20}];

TableForm[{Range[2, 20], list}, TableHeadings -> {{"n", "a[n]"}}, TableDirections -> Row]
```

For *Mathematica* versions 10.0, 10.1 or 10.2 add the option `TableAlignments -> Center` to get around this bug:

- [TableDirections example produces an error message](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95321/121)

Comment: The specified setting for the option GridBoxOptions, RowAlignments cannot be used.

Comment: @rhermans Yes, which is what I need to look at.  It appears to be a bug in `TableForm`.  Nevertheless the output appears correct, no?

Comment: @rhermans Turns out it's a known bug I hadn't noticed until today: [(95321)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95321/121)

Comment: You are correct. +1

Comment: Thanks. Although it gives an error, it works.

Comment: Just curious if you know some way to make the a0 into a subscript 0 like a_0 in LaTeX. I tried the subscript option but that totally screws it up.

Comment: @Fahim Subscripts are not fully integrated in *Mathematica* and they frequently cause trouble.  I recommend *not* using them in the course of evaluation most of the time, and instead inserting them only in output formatting.  For example you could use:  `TableForm[{Range[2, 20], list}, TableHeadings -> {{"n", HoldForm[Subscript[a, n]]}}, 
  TableDirections -> Row] /. a0 -> HoldForm[Subscript[a, 0]]`.  This uses `ReplaceAll` (short form `/.`).  To make a subscript work within your original `RecurrenceTable` expression you will need to Symbolize it with the Notation package.

Comment: Wow that works really well. Yeah I meant in the output. Working with subscripts would be ugly. Thanks!

Comment: Just wondering if it's possible to add a column with x powers traversing the range of n we put? Like x^2 to x^20 for this case in a 3rd column. Superscript could be harder so we can leave that.

Comment: @Fahim Do you mean like this? `TableForm[{Range[2, 20], list, HoldForm[x]^Range[2, 20]}, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"n", "a[n]"}}, TableDirections -> Row, TableAlignments -> Center]`

Comment: Yep thank you so much!